# Is there a way for new windows to not lose focus of other software, similar to Win's virtual keyboard

Tags: electron, focus, blur

When I click on a new window, don't take the focus away from other software, well like the virtual keyboard on Win.

```js
// kiosk: true,
// alwaysOnTop: true,
// focusable: false,
// fullscreen: false,

// show: false, // then newWin.showInactive()
```

Various combinations, still not working.